# Query SQLCe Database with array

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server-ce

Say I have this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Articles
WHERE ArtName = @par1
```

Here, `@par1` would be an array. Now what I want to do, is querying the database for all records that have their `ArtName` contained in `@par1`'s array. Is this possible? I figure I can just perform a loop and query every single item in the array, but I was hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Articles
WHERE ArtName IN ('Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3')
```